# One virtual host not responding to subdomains while all others work

Tags: windows-server-2008, subdomain, httpd.conf

I have a server at work that is running windows server 2008.  I have installed wamp on it and use it to host all my sites.  For multiple sites, I include the following into the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.NewURL.com
    ServerAlias NewURL.com *.NewUrl.com
    DocumentRoot "X:/www/NewURL/"
</VirtualHost>
```

After saving the httpd.conf file, I open up my DNS Manager, add the domain, and add 2 a records.  The "Name" of the first is set to * (Making the FQDN = *.NewURL.com).  I change the IP address to my servers local address (Let's say, 192.158.5.5).

This process has worked great for about 40-50 URLs, even allowing me to customerName.OldURL.com and still correctly retrieving the index.php file.

I have a new site I added to my httpd.conf file as well as my DNS manager.  The website is available 100% while within my work ip address range, but when I test the site at home, only the main domain (www.NewURL.com) is reachable, not clientName.NewURL.com.  clientName.NewURL.com times out and is unreachable according to www.isup.me.  However, NewURL.com works just fine.

I've set up NewURL.com exactly as I have all the other URLs I'm running of this server.  I've event gone through and started again from scratch... with the same result.

Anybody know of anything else I can check other than the virtual host settings and the DNS manager?

Comment: Does `www.NewURL.com` resolve to the correct IP address? Did you check to make sure all authoritative nameservers for the domain reply with the correct information?

Comment: Yes, the IP resolves from outside connections to the correct IP address.  Like I said, I can view the main url (i.e. - NewURL.com) just not when I have a subdomain (i.e. - customerName.NewURL.com)